# Timestamp format in Xively

Tags: timestamp, xively, netduino

I'm writing a simple application for Netduino which sends some data in CSV format to Xively.
When sending multiple entry in CSV I must include a timestamp for each value.
The message I send is this:

```
Sensor no. 1,0,2014-05-01T23:20:40Z
Sensor no. 2,0,2014-05-01T23:20:40Z
Sensor no. 3,0,2014-05-01T23:20:40Z
```

I receive always a status code 400, with this message:"CSV Parser Error: Invalid timestamp".
The timestamp is in ISO 8601 format. Where am i making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself.
The format must be the ISO 8601, but the timestamp must be in the second position, something like this:

```
sample,timestamp,value
```